# How to install Arial font (and other Windows fonts) in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, .ttf

How to install Arial font in Ubuntu?

I found many ways to install fonts in Ubuntu but I didn't find any proper way or method to install (particularly) Arial fonts in Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Simply run

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo fc-cache -f
```

in a terminal.

After that, check with

```
fc-match Arial
```

Comment: `sudo apt install fontconfig` for `sudo fc-cache -f` and `fc-match Ariel` commands.

Comment: See @barsmaga solution below... One may need to accept EULA before installing the fonts, to make this work.
`echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | sudo debconf-set-selections` and then 
`sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer --reinstall`

Comment: Thanks. This works on 22.04.

Answer (score 19):

Since the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` mechanism mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/651442) is still broken in Ubuntu 18.04 and I could not find a suitable mirror server for it to fix it, I propose to use this manual mechanism instead to install the very same fonts:

1. Install `cabextract`, a tool needed to unpack self-extracting `.exe` archives:

   ```
   sudo apt install cabextract
   ```
2. Download the font package provided via [this page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/) (also note the EULA there):

   ```
   wget https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
   ```
3. Unpack, twice:

   ```
   tar -xzf webfonts.tar.gz
   cd msfonts/
   cabextract *.exe
   ```
4. Move the fonts to your user's directory for installing additional fonts:

   ```
   cp *.ttf *.TTF ~/.local/share/fonts/
   ```
5. Restart the software in which you want to use the fonts, and they should be ready to use.

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 18.04. Just before you run `cp *.ttf *.TTF ~/.local/share/fonts/`, make sure you create or have `/font` directory there.

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 19.04 in as well.

Answer (score 18):

I have been getting LiberationSans-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Regular" for sudo fc-match Arial

So I tried following to make it work :

1) Create directory to download fonts to:  `sudo mkdir ~/ms-fonts/`

2) `cd ~/ms-fonts/`

3)  Download fonts manually :

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/comic32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/courie32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/georgi32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/impact32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/times32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/trebuc32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/verdan32.exe
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/webdin32.exe
```

4) sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer and follow  instructions. When asked, use full path to directory where fonts were downloaded i.e. `/home/root2/ms-fonts/`

5) `sudo fc-cache`

6) Check if installation is done successfully or not : `sudo fc-match Arial`

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can simple download those files and extract and move all `.ttf` files to `~/.local/share/fonts` directory

Comment: btw the above answer did not work on elementary os 0.4.1 based on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The only method that works for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 8):

I search for a solution for similar problems when preparing the docker file.

When you install fonts with the same command:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

A license agreement is not applied and Arial and other fonts are not installed!

You can use this solution:

```
echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

And you can check the result with the command:

```
fc-match Arial
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This finally resolved my problem!
`echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | sudo debconf-set-selections`
`sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer --reinstall`
`fc-match Arial`

Comment: I can cofirm that my problem was originally solved by @barsmanga's answer. However, it came back again and was then solved by @igormcoelho's suggestion to use `--reinstall`

Answer (score 7):

The `ttf-mscorefonts` package mentioned in the other answers contains a very limited selection of fonts, and rather outdated versions of them.

To get a better selection of up-to-date fonts, you can instead rip them from a Windows installation. Microsoft itself provides free virtual machine images of Win 11, ostensibly for "testing sites on MS Edge", which you can use for this.

***Distributing* fonts obtained this way is probably illegal, but *using* them yourself may or may not be be fine.**

1. Get an image [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/), select "VirtualBox".

   The filenames below will be different depending on the VM image version.
2. `unzip WinDev2301Eval.VirtualBox.zip` - this might take a while
3. `tar -xf 'WinDev2301Eval.ova'` - this might take a while
4. ```
   sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
   sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
   sudo guestmount -a 'WinDev2301Eval-disk001.vmdk' -i --ro /mnt/foo
   sudo cp -r /mnt/foo/Windows/Fonts/ .
   sudo umount /mnt/foo
   sudo rm -r /mnt/foo
   sudo mv Fonts WindowsFonts
   ```

Now you should have a `WindowsFonts` directory in the current directory, containing all the fonts you want.

- To install them for all users, copy it to `/usr/local/share/fonts`.
- To install it just for yourself, run `sudo chown -R "$USER:$USER" WindowsFonts` to change the owner to yourself, then copy the directory to `~/.local/share/fonts/`.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

1. Open software manager if its mint or Ubuntu software center if you
   are using Ubuntu
2. Search for `ttf-mscorefonts`
3. Install it

Comment: Can't confirm this answer for Ubuntu 19.04