# How to install fonts in 20.04

Tags: fonts

My fresh version of ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have the font "Times new roman" and others.
How do I get them? I tried this path:

https://linuxconfig.org/install-microsoft-fonts-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-desktop
That didn't work. I tried to restart also.
I also tried

[How to install Arial font (and other Windows fonts) in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651441/how-to-install-arial-font-and-other-windows-fonts-in-ubuntu)

In the comments section I found an alternative method but I'm stuck in the last step. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :).

Alternative method from Stefan1:

> ```
> sudo mkdir ~/ms-fonts/
> cd ms-fonts
> sudo wget ***.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
> sudo tar -xzf webfonts.tar.gz
> cd msfonts
> sudo apt install cabextract
> sudo cabextract *.exe
> sudo cp *.ttf *.TTF ~/.local/share/fonts/
> sudo fc-cache -vr
> ```

I replaced the *** with www otherwise it wouldn't work.
But the next last step ( `sudo cp *.ttf *.TTF ~/.local/share/fonts/` )
gives me problems. The terminal "says" there's no folder. What to do?
I have a folder called `usr/local/share/fonts` but it's empty, is that the one where they need to go? And how do I get them there?

Here is the terminal output after trying the alternative method:

```
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~$ sudo mkdir ~/ms-fonts/
[sudo] password for m: 
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~$ cd ms-fonts
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$  sudo wget ***.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
--2021-07-03 18:17:58--  http://***.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
Resolving ***.freedesktop.org (***.freedesktop.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘***.freedesktop.org’
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$  sudo wget www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
--2021-07-03 18:18:47--  http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
Resolving www.freedesktop.org (www.freedesktop.org)... 131.252.210.176, 2610:10:20:722:a800:ff:feda:470f
Connecting to www.freedesktop.org (www.freedesktop.org)|131.252.210.176|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz [following]
--2021-07-03 18:18:48--  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/webfonts/webfonts.tar.gz
Connecting to www.freedesktop.org (www.freedesktop.org)|131.252.210.176|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3326635 (3.2M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘webfonts.tar.gz’

webfonts.tar.gz     100%[===================>]   3.17M   860KB/s    in 3.9s    

2021-07-03 18:18:52 (826 KB/s) - ‘webfonts.tar.gz’ saved [3326635/3326635]

m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$ ls
webfonts.tar.gz
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$  sudo tar -xzf webfonts.tar.gz
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$ ls
msfonts  webfonts.tar.gz
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts$ cd msfonts/
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts/msfonts$  sudo apt install cabextract
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cabextract is already the newest version (1.9-3).
cabextract set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts/msfonts$  sudo cabextract *.exe
Extracting cabinet: andale32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting andale.inf
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting AndaleMo.TTF
  extracting ADVPACK.DLL
  extracting W95INF32.DLL
  extracting W95INF16.DLL
Extracting cabinet: arial32.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Ariali.TTF
  extracting Arialbd.TTF
  extracting Arialbi.TTF
  extracting Arial.TTF
Extracting cabinet: arialb32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting AriBlk.TTF
Extracting cabinet: comic32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Comicbd.TTF
  extracting Comic.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe
Extracting cabinet: courie32.exe
  extracting cour.ttf
  extracting courbd.ttf
  extracting courbi.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting couri.ttf
  extracting fontinst.exe
Extracting cabinet: georgi32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Georgiaz.TTF
  extracting Georgiab.TTF
  extracting Georgiai.TTF
  extracting Georgia.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe
Extracting cabinet: impact32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Impact.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
Extracting cabinet: times32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Times.TTF
  extracting Timesbd.TTF
  extracting Timesbi.TTF
  extracting Timesi.TTF
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
Extracting cabinet: trebuc32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Trebucit.TTF
  extracting Trebuc.TTF
  extracting Trebucbd.TTF
  extracting Trebucbi.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
Extracting cabinet: verdan32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Verdanab.TTF
  extracting Verdanai.TTF
  extracting Verdanaz.TTF
  extracting Verdana.TTF
Extracting cabinet: webdin32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
m@m-ThinkPad-T520:~/ms-fonts/msfonts$  sudo cp *.ttf *.TTF ~/.local/share/fonts/
cp: target '/home/m/.local/share/fonts/' is not a directory
```

Comment: Install this package `apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to install microsoft fonts.

Comment: hi Michal. I tried sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer, Ii still dont have the fonts after installing.

Comment: Run `sudo fc-cache -fv` to update font cache and then `fc-list` to list all installed fonts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: "Run sudo fc-cache -fv to update font cache and then fc-list to list all installed fonts. "  worked :) thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

After following Michal Przybylowicz's advice it is working.

I used the following command for installing the fonts:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then:

`sudo fc-cache -fv`
to update the fonts cache and

`fc-list` to list all the installed fonts.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one
Download new times Roman here https://freefontsfamily.com/times-new-roman-font-free/
Extract the zip file. Open the extracted , open the first font file, a new window will pop. On your top right corner you will see an install button, go ahead and install, repeat this for all the font weights.